# Does MEF support UWP projects?

Tags: asp.net, .net, uwp, mef

i have been searching on whether UWP projects can be implemented with Managed Extensibility Framework.

On the [GitHub depository](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism)
of Prism, it says

> MEF is supported with WPF for compatibility with previous versions.
> It will not be added to Windows 10 UWP or Xamarin Forms.

(It is for Prism.Mef. But, can it not be for MEF generally?)

on [Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) it is said:

> MEF is an integral part of the .NET Framework 4, and is available wherever the .NET Framework is used. You can use MEF in your client applications, whether they use Windows Forms, WPF, or any other technology, or in server applications that use ASP.NET.

Is UWP included in *"any other technology"* part or with the *"in server applications that use ASP.NET"* part?

I know .NET Core is used for UWP applications, but that ASP.NET part confuses me.

Briefly,is it possible to write UWP applications with MEF? Answers with sources will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can try their packages for .NET Core, as UWP should support .NET Core packages in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is for Prism.Mef. But, can it not be for MEF generally?

For Prism.Mef **only**

> Is UWP included in "any other technology" part or with the "in server applications that use ASP.NET" part?

UWP is included in "any other technology" part

> Briefly,is it possible to write UWP applications with MEF?

Yes, by using the [`Microsoft.Composition` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Composition), we can easily integrate MEF in UWP app.

Here is an [article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/12/20/mef-for-windows-store-apps.aspx) for Windows Store app(8.1), it is similar with UWP app.

And this is a UWP MEF sample: [Link](https://github.com/LibertyOrganization/CommonRepo/tree/master/01.Projects/02.UWP%20Untils/uwp_MEF)